# Removed question: my edit still shows in reputation log, but not in suggestions log

Tags: support, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I have lost 2 rep today; after some investigation it relates to an edit made last year to a question that has now been deleted. Fine, but this edit seems to have vanished from my 'suggestions' action log. Why is this? I thought the action log showed everything I had done,  whether or not the relevant question still existed.
I have the 'include removed posts' checkbox ticked, and removed posts are visible elsewhere in the log.

Comment: nah, several of those tabs under activity only show things that aren't deleted.

Comment: Honestly not sure how I can clarify this much. I can't link to the relevant edited/removed question, would screenshots help? @Kevin has effectively answered anyway.